# How structure my angularjs app

Tags: javascript, html, templates, angularjs

I don't know how to "include" partials on templates. For example, I've an template "index". When the user navigate to "/" I like re render some divs on "index" from partials (login box and some others text div), when de user navigate to "/newAccount" I like re render same divs on "index" but with others partials.

The question is, it's the correcly way to use of AngularJS? Similar to the includes on Facelets?

Thanks! ;)

Here a pseudo code of my idea:

**Template:**

```
<html>
  <body>....{include:mainBox}....{include:foot}...</body>
</html>
```

**Partials for /newAccount:**

{define mainBox}

```
<div>New user</div>
<div>Username:<input/></div>
```

{define foot}

```
<div>...</div>
```

**Update:**

Some like this is wrong?

```
function IndexCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.mainPage = 'partials/index/loginbox.html',
    $scope.footPage = 'partials/index/footer.html',
}
```

After in the template I put:

```
<div ng-include="mainPage"></div>
...
<div ng-include="footPage"></div>
```

And the route:

```
when('/', {
       templateUrl: 'partials/index/layout.html',
       controller: IndexCtrl
   })
```

Comment: It's good, if the template url will never change you can put the url as string in the ng-include without creating variables in the $scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) for this. Maybe what you want is [ng-view](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angView) + [$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeProvider)